# Extract text from specific position in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, text-extraction

i wanna extract specific text from pdf i have the exactly position of the text

i try to use itext7 for the extraction but when i create the rectangle for the extraction with the correct dimension it seems too big for match the text but the dimension is correct i tried  SimpleTextExtractionStrategy and 
LocationTextExtractionStrategy same result
[pdfFile](https://filebin.net/28jtoqiquxmlu6d3/test1.pdf?t=ry878rac)

```
private void estraiValori(PdfPage page) {
    for (Entry<String, Elemento> entry : templateMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Elemento value=(Elemento) entry.getValue();


        //Rectangle tmp=new Rectangle((float)238.64,(float) 14.8,(float) 122,(float) 28.7);   

            TextRegionEventFilter  fontFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(value.getDim()); //getDim is a rectangle
            FilteredEventListener listener = new FilteredEventListener();
            //LocationTextExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = listener.attachEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), fontFilter);
            SimpleTextExtractionStrategy  extractionStrategy = listener.attachEventListener(new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy(), fontFilter);
            new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener).processPageContent(page);//page is a PdfPage

            String actualText = extractionStrategy.getResultantText();
            System.out.println(actualText);



        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you attach the PDF from which you are trying to extract data? If not then I doubt anyone can help you. Please double check your coordinates. Are you aware that in PDF the Y coordinate increases from bottom to the top?

Comment: @AlexeySubach thanks for you answer, i take coordinates from comment  and i extract rectangle from a pdf "template" through the method getRectangle().toRectangle() in PdfAnnotation so i supposed the dimension should be correct i try to test also manual just for do some test but the result is incorrect either  pdf link ---> https://filebin.net/28jtoqiquxmlu6d3/test1.pdf?t=ry878rac

Comment: pdf2Data, which you used to mark up the template, uses some heuristics to extract the text. The data field area in question does contain text visually (and it is extracted by pdf2Data), but formally when iText determines whether the text lies completely inside the rectangle it considers ascenders and descenders of the glyphs, and those might be bigger than the "colorful" area of the glyph, hence your problems. If you really want to write your own code for that you will have to use larger rectangles.

Comment: @AlexeySubach but  i have the opposite problem i take more text than i expect or i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to show (visually) same content in PDF. You can append text glyph by glyph, or in whole sentences. `TextRegionEventFilter` does not split bigger chunks of text into smaller ones before filtering. If text was written in a big chunk and you want only a part of it, the raw content needs to be preprocessed, i.e. split into smaller chunks.

Fortunately, iText provides an out of the box way to do that - the class is called `GlyphTextEventListener` and it can be chained to the other `ITextExtractionStrategy` instances. Just wrap your listener into `ITextExtractionStrategy` in the following way:

```
TextRegionEventFilter filter =  new TextRegionEventFilter(new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2));
ITextExtractionStrategy filteredListener = new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
ITextExtractionStrategy fineGrainedListener = new GlyphTextEventListener(filteredListener);

new PdfCanvasProcessor(fineGrainedListener).processPageContent(page);
```